# How do I turn my scratch webapp into a Node.js app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, web-applications

I basically have written a webapp from scratch. So I just used a index.html file and a bunch of js and css. Now I want to turn this into a Node.js webapp. How do I get this done in a way that doesn't require much changing of my existing code.

Comment: You should start from their [guides](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/), and use [API doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/) as reference for function, class, method you are using. If there is problem with your code then come back to ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is designed to allow the server-side execution of JavaScript code. As, if I understand it right, this is a thing that you don't need I am curious why you want to use Node.js. The only thing you want to do is deliver your project files to a client (browser).

Although you could start a HTTP server which delivers the file of your project using JavaScript, this requires much of unnecessary boilerplate code that you don't need to write to get your project live. I would recommend using a regular HTTP server, which is designed to do exactly what you need: deliver files to the client.

Nginx is a lightweight HTTP server, which is easy to configure. Just set the root folder of your project as the HTTP root and nginx will deliver the requested file by itself.

To get started, head over to the [Beginners Guide of nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html).

An alternative to nginx would be the Apache HTTP server.

Comment: Node.js is not just for server side but you can still use it as client side either. For an example: I use node packages (npm) like FontAwesome, Bootstrap and then I use node.js to create my own task runner to copy files from **node_modules** folder to my **assets** folder after the command `npm update`.